# istream to vector with struct conversion

Tags: c++, vector, struct, ifstream, readfile

I have got file with vector of :

```
typedef struct {
    float fX; ///< position X
    float fY; ///< position Y
    int iSize; ///< Size of point   
} structParams;
```

but I would like to read it to vector of nearly the same struct but without iSize

```
typedef struct {
    float fX; ///< position X eq. structParams.fX
    float fY; ///< position Y eq. structParams.fY
} structPositionParams;
```

Can I do this in similar way to

```
ifstream inStr("file.dat");
vector<structPositionParams>  oVector;
oVector.(numOfElements);
inStr.read((char*)&oVector[0], sizeof(structPositionParams) * numOfElements);
inStr.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got to utilize the *stride* of the data. Since the standard library doesn't support reading strided data in any way, either you read the whole file, and then run a for loop creating objects from that data, or do whole reading in a for loop, skipping `sizeof(int)` after each object.